# Windows port of jwhois?

Tags: windows, linux, gnu, whois

Other than UnxUtils or GnuWin32, does anyone know of any Windows ports of the GNU `jwhois` utility?  UnxUtils contains a very old version (2.4.1) that no longer works properly, and GnuWin32 crashes every time I issue a query.

Answer (score 0):

1. Jwhois **works for me** without errors
2. I don't know another ports, but, from the other side whois in Sysinternals Suite can handle any TLD